# Passing value to const reference parameter?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

I haven't been able to find a similar question on here, or through Google, maybe because i don't know if I'm asking the right question, so not sure if the title is right. But I'm working with code that looks like this:

```
Foo * foo = new Foo();
add(*foo); //Couldnt find any similar questions on this syntax?

void add(const Foo & foo){

//What exactly is foo here? How can i manipulate its members, foo. or foo-> ?

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `foo` inside the `add` method is a constant reference. It behaves like a pointer in the sense that it does not copy the object: you interact with it as if it were the object itself. Unlike a pointer, a reference cannot be `NULL`, and it cannot be reassigned. You interact with it using a dot `.` operator instead of the `->` operator.

```
void add(const Foo & foo){
    cout << foo.first_member << endl;
    foo.const_member_function();
}
```

Since `foo` is a constant reference, you can read `foo`'s members, but you cannot assign them. Also, any calls of member functions on the `foo` reference are limited to functions explicitly marked `const`.

Calling `add` with a dereferenced `foo` is OK, as long as `foo` is not `NULL`. Making a reference by dereferencing a `NULL` pointer is undefined behavior.

Comment: It behaves like the object itself, not like a pointer at all.

Comment: @EJP I clarified my point about references behaving like pointers.

Answer (score 3):

'foo' is a constant reference. You can access its members via foo.fred, foo.method(), etc., but you can't change any data members or call any non-const methods.